# PHP Pagination with x amount of pages

Tags: php, pagination

Currently I have a functioning pagination script, although I'm missing on feature. At the moment it's possible for hundreds of pages to be showing in the $pages list, because there's no filter on to show between, for example, [1] [...] 5, 6, 7 [..] [45]. Here's my code:

```
    /** Pagination **/
    $limit = 7;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
    $result = $db->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();
    $pages_query = $result->fetchColumn(0);
        $count = number_format($pages_query);
        $pages = ceil($pages_query / $limit);
    $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    ob_start();
        echo("<span class='alignright'>");
        if ($pages >= 1 && $page <= $pages){
            if($page > 1){
                $next = ($page - 1);
                $link = "?page=$next";
                echo("<a class='paginate' href='$link'><i class='icon-caret-left'></i></a>");
            }
        for ($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){
            echo ($x == $page) ? "<strong style='font-weight: bold!important;'><a class='paginate' href='?page=$x'>$x</a></strong>" : "<a class='paginate' href='?page=$x'>$x</a>";
        }
        if($page < $pages){
            $next = ($page + 1);
            $link = "?page=$next";
            echo("<a class='paginate' href='$link'><i class='icon-caret-right'></i></a>");
        }
        echo("</span>");
        if($count > 0){
            echo("<span class='smalltext'>Page <strong class='half'>$page</strong> of $pages:</span>");
        } else {
            echo("<span class='smalltext'>There are <span class='half'>$count</span> results to display.</span>");
        }
    $pagintion = ob_get_clean();
```

(It's been stripped from other junk that was in it but that's the general frame.) Basically I'm trying to figure out how to limit it to have "between pages" down the bottom as specified in the top part of the question. Something like:
 [<] [1] ... [4] [5] [6] ... [45] [>]
If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can try LIMIT with in your query itself

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT STARTING_RESULT_NUMBER, RESULTS_PER_PAGE

RESULTS_PER_PAGE is no.of items per page you want to display
STARTING_RESULT_NUMBER =(CURRENT_PAGE_NUMBER*RESULTS_PER_PAGE)

Comment: He already has the limit, he wants to display the pagination like this  **[<] [1] ... [4] [5] [6] ... [45] [>]**

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the list of pages to something like `[<] [1] ... [4] [5] [6] ... [45] [>]` rather than showing all pages numbers, you can replace your `for` loop by something like :

```
echo "<a class='paginate' href='?page=1'>1</a>";
if($page > 3) {echo "...";}
if($page > 2) {echo "<a class='paginate' href='?page=" . $x-1 . "'>" . $x-1 "</a>";}
if($page != 1 && $page != pages) {echo "<a class='paginate' href='?page=" . $x . "'>" . $x "</a>";}
if($page < $pages-1) {echo "<a class='paginate' href='?page=" . $x+1 . "'>" . $x+1 "</a>";}
if($page < $pages-2) {echo "...";}
if($pages >1) {echo "<a class='paginate' href='?page=1'>1</a>";}
```

Il will show the first page, the last pages, the current pages and the ones just before and just after.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't seem to work. It didn't show any pages in between, only the first and last unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

My personal meaning with pagination is that it must be readable and simple to change later on.
I typed the following code based on you're example:

```
$totalPages = 145; //the total amount of pages
$selectedPage = 40; //the selected page

$pages = array(); //the array which is gonna hold the pages we need to display
$offset = 3; //the number of pages to select around the selected page

$closePages = range($selectedPage - $offset, $selectedPage + $offset); //select the pages that are in $offset of the selected page

array_filter($closePages, function($x) { //filter the pages below 1 and above $totalPages
    return ($x <= $totalPages && $x >= 1 ? true : false ); 
});

array_push($pages, 1); //add the first page
array_push($pages, '...'); //add some dots

$pages = array_merge($pages, $closePages);

array_push($pages, '...'); //and again add some dots
array_push($pages, $totalPages); //add the last page
```

Then you use a foreach loop to display the pages:

```
foreach($pages as $page) {
    if (is_numeric($page)) {

        if ($page != $selectedPage) $content .= ' <a href="?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
        else $content .= ' <a href="?page=' . $page . '"><strong>' . $page . '</strong></a> ';

    } else 
        $content .= '[...]';
}
```

Some explanation after you're comment on this answer:

The $totalPages variable must be the total amount of pages on the page (from you're example) and the $selectedPage is the page that is selected at this moment.

```
$totalPages = ceil($pages_query / $limit);
$selectedPage = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
```

Comment: I'm confused as how to implement this. I'm assuming my $totalPages would equal to $pages and $selectedPage would equal $page, right? I tried implementing the code and nothing showed up for the pages.

Comment: @JordanLovelle , I added some explanation below the answer. If you don't get any result, try to fill in some random numbers to test it.